# Why does Visual Studio start localdb and how can I stop that?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to optimize my Visual Studio experience and my machine in general.  I noticed that I have two instances of SQL Server running, one of which is LocalDB.  This gets started by Visual Studio.

I would rather it didnt start local db at all but I can imagine it uses it for a few things.  Since I already have a full sql instance running it would be better if it used that.

Does anyone know if I can stop this from starting or at least not starting it until it really needs it?

Comment: Do you mean the SQL Server Express instance that is installed with VS2013 and starts on computer startup? You can start `services.msc` and stop the `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)` and `SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS)` services. If you want to make sure they don't start on computer startup, set them to "Disabled" in the properties dialog box. This will save you some resources both on startup and in general computer use.

Comment: Is that happens, only when you open a specific project or for all projects, if for any specific project, please post your app.config/web.config

Comment: I have submitted a connect item for this, if you want it to happen vote it up! https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1694246

Answer (score 11):

The following procedure worked for me.

*(Caveat: I don't use LocalDB at all, so I don't care if this procedure disables it completely. You may feel differently.)*

1. Make sure Visual Studio is not running.
2. Run Visual Studio and go to the SQL Server Object Explorer.
3. Right-click each LocalDB instance and choose Delete, or if Delete is
   unavailable, choose Disconnect.
4. Close Visual Studio.
5. Kill all sqlservr.exe instances that were launched by Visual Studio.
6. Go to
   **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\SSDT\SqlServerObjectExplorer**
   and verify that it has no ServerInstance subkeys, for example ServerInstance1, ServerInstance2, etc.
7. Rename **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
       Server Local DB** so Visual Studio can't find it (for example, append
       **.DISABLED** to the key name).
8. Run Visual Studio and enjoy your LocalDB-free experience.

Please note that you will need to repeat this procedure every time you install an update to SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), since the installer re-adds the key you renamed.

Comment: Verified this procedure works as described.  Very helpful.  Pretty annoying Visual Studio creates this memory sucking instance if it's not being used.  Should be a more explicit option.

Comment: It seems to me that you can rename "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\LocalDB\Binn\sqlservr.exe" just as easy.

Comment: The first 5 steps took care of most of the memory bloat for me.

Answer (score 3):

LocalDB does not run as a service like SQL Server Express.  It will start and stop/automatically as needed.

> LocalDB doesn't create any database services; LocalDB processes are
>   started and stopped automatically when needed. The application is just
>   connecting to "Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0" and LocalDB process is
>   started as a child process of the application. A few minutes after the
>   last connection to this process is closed the process shuts down.

[Introducing LocalDB, an improved SQL Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlexpress/introducing-localdb-an-improved-sql-express) - SQL Server Express Blog

Comment: Yes, I know that.  My question was why does Visual Studio start it.  Im assuming it's for SQL database project compilation.  I would rather that VS used my already running SQL instance and save the ram for better things.